# Prove $φ(R^2)$ where $φ(u,v)=(v\cos u,v\sin u,bu)$ is the smooth function.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

Prove $φ(R^2)$ is a smooth surface and $φ(u,v)=(v\cos u,v\sin u,bu)$   $R^2\rightarrow R^3$ and b>0 constant. Its rank $Dφ$ is 2, so I'm ok with that part. Only thing to prove is  that it has an continuous inverse so $φ$  can be an acceptable parametrization. Can i just argue the topology definition . I know the existence of the inverse hence if the pre image of the inverse  of open sets of$ R^2$ are open in $R^3$  then the inverse is continuous.But still that needs proof

Comment: It makes little sense to say "where $\varphi$ is a smooth function" and then to define it explicitly.

Comment: thats how the problem was presented . I know its a redundancy.

Comment: What's $b$, a non-zero constant?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Well, first it is a redundancy, but it's also not quite correct language-wise, because the enlish article "a" means "some". So, if you write "where $\varphi$ is a smooth function", it can be _any_ smooth function. Then defining it explicitly is actually a contradiction in itself. It is correct to write "where $\varphi$ is _the_ smooth function $\varphi(u,v) = (v\cos u,v\sin u, bu)$".

Comment: @amsmath tahnk you for the correction.

Comment: @MeesdeVries yes positive

Comment: I think what you proved is enough. What would you like to have a "continuous inverse"?

Comment: the definition of a surface is that there exist a mapping smooth  1-1 and onton with continuous inverse and rank of jacobian 2

Comment: Well, "onto" is not a problem. Have you proved that $\varphi$ is 1-1, yet?

Comment: yes i did that part. there are no 2 different $(u_1,v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$  such that their image is the same it has to be $u_1=u_2$ and $v_1=v_2$ only think that remains is continuous iverse. Can i just argue the topology definition . I know the existence of the inverse hence if the pre image of the inverse  of open sets of$ R^2$ are open in $R^3$ it is continuous.

Comment: The inverse is $\varphi^{-1}(x,y,z) = (\tfrac z b,\,x\cos\tfrac z b + y\sin\tfrac z b)^T$.

Comment: what T stands for?

Comment: That's just the transpose to make it a column vector. You can leave it away.

Comment: $(xco(z/b)+ysin(z/b))cos(z/b)=x$ i dont see it

Comment: Outline comment: Please learn LaTeX. The users are thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M := \varphi(\Bbb R^2)$. Then $\varphi : \Bbb R^2\to M$ is obviously onto and you proved that it is also injective. Furthermore, the rank of the Jacobian is $2$ in each point (which you also proved). Now, the inverse of $\varphi$ is given by
$$
\psi(x,y,z) = \left(\frac z b\,,\,x\cos\frac z b+y\sin\frac z b\right),\quad (x,y,z)\in M.
$$
This is easily verifyable by computing $\psi(\varphi(u,v))$. So, $\varphi^{-1}$ is obviously continuous.

Comment: how did ou come up with it? any sort tricks?

Comment: When you write $\varphi(u,v) = (x,y,z)$, then $u = z/b$ and $v\binom{cos z/b}{\sin z/b} = \binom x y$. Taking the scalar product with $\binom{cos z/b}{\sin z/b}$ gives $v = \langle\binom x y,\binom{cos z/b}{\sin z/b}\rangle = x\cos z/b + y\sin z/b$.